# Define function which gives random values in a given range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a blackjack game in python with no `graphics` or `pygame`, but I need it so if they use the `hit` option it should give them a card with totally other value. I have looked at [In python, is there anyway to have a variable be a different random number everytime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611589/in-python-is-there-anyway-to-have-a-variable-be-a-different-random-number-every), and also many other websites. I have got no information about how to do this.
Code :D

```py
suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10,'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}

###Printing Random
s = lambda: secure_choice.choice(suits)
r = lambda: secure_choice.choice(ranks)
ds = secure_choice.choice(suits)
dr = secure_choice.choice(ranks)
v = values.get(r)
dv = values.get(dr)


def pullCard():
    print(f"You pulled a {r} of {s} the value is {v}")
    print(f"The dealer pulled a {dr} of {ds} the value is {dv}")



def dealerOnly():
    print('You standed')



pullCard()

Answer = str(input('Do you want to Hit or Stand?')).lower()
if Answer == 'stand':
    dealerOnly()
elif Answer == 'hit':
    pullCard()
```

What I think could work:

```
def ReValueCard():
    s = secure_choice.choice(suits)
    r = secure_choice.choice(ranks)
```

Comment: Why didn't the link you looked at work? Side note: you want a *function* that gives random values... not a variable.

Comment: We would need to see `secure_choice` as well to help you since that is what is giving you a card here.

Comment: Also, in theory you should create a collection of all 52 cards, then draw randomly from that collection and remove it so that it cannot be chosen again.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb `secure_choice = random.SystemRandom()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is to do this and change the variables with what need to match. Use the python built-in import `random` for this, and use the defined command, `random.randint` to find your random card

```py
import random

oldcard = 7
# the old card would be updated with every last old card
while randomcard == oldcard:
    randomcard = random.randint(2, 11)
else:
    print(randomcard)
```

hope that this helps!

if you just need it to be a random card everytime, and not a different random card, you can just do this:

```py
import random

randomcard = random.randint(2, 11)

print(randomcard)
```

if you want a random suit too, just apply the `random.randint` command for 1-4 and then just define each one as what suit

:D

Answer (score 2):

Individual random number generation with stuff like `random.randint`/`random.choice`/`random.randrange` has issues with avoiding repeats (you don't want to deal five Aces from a single deck after all). The simplest solution is to actually make a deck of *all* the values, shuffle it, and deal from it in order, just like in the real world.

To make your deck, you just take the `product` of the suits and ranks:

```
import itertools
import random

suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')

deck = list(itertools.product(suits, ranks))
```

then you shuffle it with the rather obviously named `random.shuffle`:

```
random.shuffle(deck)  # Shuffles in place
```

Now, to deal from the deck, just pop off cards on demand:

```
randomcard = deck.pop()
```

If they choose to hit again, just call `deck.pop()` again to get a random, but non-repeating, card. If you want to deal from multiple decks to make card counting harder, just multiply your deck before shuffling:

```
deck = list(itertools.product(suits, ranks)) * 5  # Deal from five decks, not 1
```

Comment: This might work But its says `You pulled a ('Clubs','4')`

Comment: @PythonLuaMaster: Sure. It's kept in `tuple` form to make it more programmatically useful (e.g. distinguishing values for blackjack, or distinguishing suits to detect a flush in poker), but when you display it for the user, you'd format it appropriately, e.g. `suit, rank = randomcard` to unpack the pieces to useful names (optionally, skip `randomcard` entirely and just do `suit, rank = deck.pop()`), then `print(f"You pulled a {rank} of {suit}")` to display it to the user.